# ASP.NET Font not working with some computers in my network

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm using an installed font inside my ASP.NET local website but some computers in my network not getting the font and it is already installed in it

when I use CSS  `@font-face`  with the same font as custom font my site does not read the font at all

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MhndB";
    src: url("/font/AL-Mohanad.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "FSAlbert";
    src: url(/font/FSAlbertArabic-Regular.otf) format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "MOHAND";
    src: url(/font/MOHAND.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

the first and second fonts working prefect but the third one is the font I'm facing the problem with

and this is my body tag for the installed font :

```
<body style="background-color: bisque; font-family:'AL-Mohanad Bold'">
```

and this is my body tag when trying to use the custom font :

```
<body style="background-color: bisque; font-family:'MOHAND'">
```

I think my font file is corrupted that is why it does not work  as custom font I tried to fix it and convert it using many websites but also not working

but why the installed font work with some computers but other computers not working with it?

I prefers to use the custom font way

any ideas to make it work ?